# Locally finite - equivalent (?) definition

Tags: general-topology

A collection $(U_i)_i$ of open subsets of a topological space $X$ is called *locally finite* if every point $x \in X$ has a neighborhood $V_x$ that intersects only finitely many of the $U_i$'s. Clearly this implies that $x$ itself only lies in finitely many $U_i$'s, but the converse is not true in general, I think. Is there a good counterexample? And are there assumptions on $X$ under which the converse holds, i.e., local finiteness can be checked on points themselves, instead of on neighborhoods of points?

Comment: The converse of a definition?

Comment: So you're trying to imagine a space where a point lies in finitely many of the $U_i$'s, however the second you start to extend feelers out (by thinking about any open neighborhoods of $x$) you begin to intersect infinitely many $U_i$'s. There should be a way to construct such a space.

Comment: The weaker property that every point is only contained in finitely many cover elements is called "point-finite". @IvanNeretin gave an example of a point-finite cover that is not locally finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let our collection consist of open intervals $(-1,1)$ and $\left(\dfrac1{n+1},\dfrac1n\right)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Then clearly any point belongs to finitely many $U_i$, but good luck finding an open neighborhood of $0$ that intersects finitely many of them.

Comment: Thanks for your example. And since we can do the same with the space $[-1,1]$, which is compact, Hausdorff, contractible, simply connected, locally Euclidean,... I guess that there are no reasonable conditions on the space to ensure that such a thing cannot happen.

Comment: I don't know that. _"There are less things in heaven and earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your topology."_ Here is one such property off the top of my head: every point should have a neighborhood which _itself_ is finite. Together with this, point-finiteness means finiteness. Sure, this property is dumb and the spaces that have it are all ugly as hell. But then again, what did you expect of a property which $[-1,1]$ _does not have?_

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of your question: *And are there assumptions on X under which the converse holds, i.e., local finiteness can be checked on points themselves, instead of on neighborhoods of points?*

Well, there is at least one such assumption, though it is trivial and therefore not much interesting. But if $X$ has the discrete topology, i.e. every point (more precisely every singleton) is open, then every point-finite collection is locally-finite.

Here is an example of a point-finite collection of intervals in the real line that is not locally-finite at $0$. Consider $\{(0,\frac1n):n=1,2,3,...\}$.

If $X$ is Hausdorff and $x$ is a non-isolated point, then one could find non-empty open sets $U_n$ and $V_n$ such that $x\in(U_{n+1}\cup V_{n+1})\subset U_n$ and $U_n\cap V_n=\varnothing$. Then $\{V_n:n=1,2,...\}$ is a disjoint open family, and $x\notin\cup\{V_n:n=1,2,...\}$. If necessary, we may add more open sets (continue transfinitely), none containing $x$, to obtain an infinite disjoint family $\mathcal V$ such that $x\in\overline{\cup\mathcal V}$, yet $x\notin\overline{V}$ for any $V\in\mathcal V$. Then $\mathcal V$ is point-finite, but it is not locally-finite at $x$.